# Jasper reports in Zend framework issues

Tags: java, php, zend-framework, jasper-reports

Hope you are fine and doing good.

I saw your reply for one of the queries relating to report generation in PHP.

I have installed zend server ce and set up php-java bridge and java files also in Windows 7.

But unfortunately for me none of the java classes are working .

Please guide me to make the same working as you have experience in setting up the same.

Will share my code with you in case needed.

regards,

Sidharth